# Oracle dblink user password change breaking things

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, change-password

I changed the password for an oracle user that was used by a db link. I used alter database link to alter their password, but things that were using this dblink failed.

Is there a command or technique to change the password of a user that has a dblink without having things (stored procedures, functions, queries) that use it fail?

Comment: you can create a database link that does not have a username/password in it, then it will try to use the current username/password to make the connection (the passwords have to match in the dbs).  would that work for you?  Also, if you drop and recreate the link with the new password, the packages will be invalid, but the first time they are accessed oracle will try to recompile them, if the db link is valid they will recompile fine and it will all work out okay

Comment: I dont think that will work as changing the password on both databases at the exact same time is not possible, is it? and the packages going invalid would be really bad as it can cause processes to fail.

Comment: so try this -- when the password changes on the remote database, at that point the procedures/packages will break.  At that point, drop and recreate your link with the new password.  The packages will still be invalid but the first time you execute them oracle will try to recompile it and it should pass since the password is now valid.  The other way, you are right, the passwords will be out of sync, but once you find out they changed the password on the remote db, change the password on your local db and it should all work

Comment: we use a service account for our db links, the password has to be changed every 90 days but we have it scheduled so all the ducks can be lined up and it can all be fixed during a down time

Comment: our environment cannot have downtime. packages cannot go invalid. I am thinking oracle is not a good fit for a system that cannot have downtime.

Comment: seems there is a link where you could hook into an ldap server, I have never done it https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5005.htm